# recovering web-browser form input data on refresh

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, form-fill

In `Firefox 3.6`, if I refresh a web page after editing form data, the refreshed page recovers the edited input data.

But in Google Chrome, the refreshed page does not recover the user input data but instead shows the default data.

*Is there a way for Google Chrome to recover input data on page refresh?*

Answer (score 0):

Use [Lazarus](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno). It is a Chrome extension that saves everything you type into forms, so that if you reload the page, you can choose anything you've previously entered into that form. It can also be password protected to prevent people from accessing your typing history without permission.

Comment: I'm trying the Lazarus, and it seems that if a input tag is not a child of a form tag, it does not work.(According to my test..). But most of the input tags in my website are not a child of a form, so the Lazarus does not work well.